# why linux kernel map physical address to virtual address

Tags: linux, kernel

In protected mode, MMU use page table to translate a virtual address to physical address, and program code use virtual address(even kernel code), kernel use pkmap_page_table to map the kernel virtual address to physical page, so WHY kernel use page_address() to map a physical page to virtual address? Is there something I ignored?

Comment: Where does kernel use page_address() to map a physical page to virtual address? page_address() just returns virtual address where page is mapped to.

Comment: Yes, Thank you. As you said : page_address() just returns virtual address where page is mapped to. Understand. Because kernel use virtual address too, so we have to find a virtual address for the mapped page. Thanks again.